# How to calculate average values for documents with different type

Tags: javascript, node.js, indexing, view, couchdb

I have a document like this

```
{
  type: 'vehicles',
  vin: 1234, 
  companyId: 123,
  _id: 321
}

{
  type: 'company',
  name: 'x company',
  _id: 123
}
{
  type: 'company',
  name: 'y company',
  _id: 333
}
```

I am trying and to design map reduce function to get Average vehicle per company (allVehicle / allCompany), and i want to get the value by calling a key like this

```
key: ["averageVehiclesPerCompany"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is perfect solution to calculate average

```
function calcAverage(companies) {
    var totalVehicle = 0;
    Object.keys(companies).map(function(key, index) {
        var vehicle = 0;
        if (!!companies[key].vin) {
            vehicle = companies[key].vin;
        }
        totalVehicle += vehicle;
    });
    return parseFloat(totalVehicle / companies.length).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: by map reduce what i meant is Couchdb map reduce functions, can i use this to create views in couchdb